# Splitting / matching faces on cone to get the faces to match when wrapped around

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, faces

I have a cone that had a hole in it and I'm trying to get all the faces to match / wrap around correctly / evenly.  I tried joining vertices with "**J**" but I get a message saying "**could not connect vertices**"

[image]

I'm using Blender 2.90.1

File with issue:

[image]

Original File where hole was created from.

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your object, maybe the edges are ripped apart?

Comment: @moonboots ok I've attached it.

Comment: Is this like grid fill the 4 x 3 face hole (after removing the 4 "long" faces currently in what I assume was the hole.

Comment: @batFINGER  Yes I included the original file showing the cylinder sticking out of it.  I wanted to delete the cylinder and fill the hole with matching faces all around.

Comment: what you share is not what you show, could you please share what you show?

Comment: @moonboots woops I thought you wanted the original file where the hole was created from.  I've included both just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 vertical edges are ripped:

[image]

If I select a vertex, here is what it gives (so you can't join the 2 opposite vertices):

[image]

So you need to delete these 4 faces + one horizontal edge that is under the faces (as pointed out by Batfinger, probably the result of a fill (<kbd>F</kbd>):

[image]

Then select the top and bottom row of vertices and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!.........

Comment: Would have thought the reason cannot join two verts is when they are already used to form an edge... was that the _"one horizontal edge under the faces"_  possibly from the first time join was used, & not appearing to work?

Comment: Perhaps F was used and not J